# Upgrade Path from Sails.JS 0.10 to 0.11 Maintaining Backwards Compatibility

Tags: node.js, socket.io, sails.js

I have a legacy Sails.JS project which is currently on Sails version 0.10.5. I'd like to upgrade the project to Sails 0.11.x and onward, but there's a catch. This project acts as the backend for a native mobile app, so unlike upgrading a web server where you can just link the new sails.io.js and socket.io client libraries into your website, we cannot rely on users to upgrade the native app.

It seems unreasonable that I'm the only one to have faced this issue, so I thought to pose the question to the community to see if there's anything brilliant that I haven't thought of to make the upgrade go seamlessly.

The ideas I've thought of are:

1. Run two versions of the application using subdomains (https://v2.domain.com/api/...). This obviously is the most obvious solution, but requires a fair amount of server configuration to pull off and we're currently running on a PAAS that has limited ability to customize the environment, so this would likely require switching providers.

   In addition to the work involved in going this route, there's the decision of what to do with the code base. You could maintain two branches of the code for the two sails versions, but that means fixing bugs twice and twice the potential for errors. Or you could put provisions in the code to check under which version of sails it's running. Neither of these seem terribly clean, but I think I'd opt for the second of the two options if it came down to this.
2. Dig through the sails.js core code, and find a way to get socket.io 0.9 and socket.io 1.0 to run side by side simultaneously. This would allow me to get all of the users to update their mobile app before switching off 0.9 support. This has obvious pitfalls as well though, chief among them performing such comprehensive changes at the framework level.

I'd love some insight into what others have done in this situation, if the solution is to just remain on Sails 0.10.5 then that's fine, but I'd love to get the added benefit of the native Socket.IO libraries that have come out for v.1.0 rather than the semi-home spun solution that I'm currently using. Also it would be nice to continue to get security and feature updates going forward.

Comment: We're facing the same problem - we have hundreds of client apps that are using the old socket.io client (packaged in the app). We'll have to run 2 sets of servers for each client - the old 0.10 ones and the new Sails 0.12 ones.

Just wondering if you implemented a solution, and how it went for you guys?

Comment: I never found anything on this, we ended up running two servers briefly. It was super frustrating, but the only surefire way of making the transition. Sorry I can't be of more assistance.

Answer (score 0):

The only sure fire solution to this problem would be to set up a nginx reverse proxy that has your current server as the base and then have another server with /v2 path prefixed before each path created then migrate users to the /v2 path as you are able to, I would recommend using the same git repo for both servers but maintain them on different branches so that you could merge new changes onto both if it happens to be needed.